# WebBrowser control - Get element By type?

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I need to get a element by type in C# the HTML looks like this:

```
<button type="submit" class="orangeBtn">Send Invitations</button>
```

And I want it to be able to where I can invoke("click") it, but it isn't appearing to work in C#. My current code is:

```
HtmlElement m_SubmitField = m_Browser.Document.All["orangeBtn"];

if (m_SubmitField != null)
    m_SubmitField.InvokeMember("click");
```

Is there an alternative working way to do this?

This is NOT my server, so I can't edit the HTML or add jquery.

I'm making an automated application to send invites to friends that I want to join, but they made the button without a id or name as seen above, so is there anyway to have it invoke("click") in C# using a different method?

Thanks.

Comment: what is your platform? asp? silverlight? winforms? wpf? (etc.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `GetElementsByTagName`.

```
var elements = m_Browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
foreach (HtmlElement element in elements)
{
     // If there's more than one button, you can check the
     //element.InnerHTML to see if it's the one you want
     if (element.InnerHTML.Contains("Send Invitations"))
     {
          element.InvokeMember("click");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i have tried the following code, and was successfull.

```
HtmlElementCollection htmlcol = ((WebBrowser)sender).Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
for (int i = 0; i < htmlcol.Count; i++)
            {
                if (htmlcol[i].GetAttribute("value") == "Search")
                {
                    htmlcol[i].InvokeMember("click");
                }
            }
```

i have tried this code for the following condition

```
<input type="submit" value="Search">
```

you can also try for such html tags and i am hopeful that it will work for you...
enjoy

Answer (score -3):

Well a button with no id or name like that will submit whatever form it is contained within - if you know the HTML, then does the form have an id?  If so you can find the form by it's id and call it's submit method.

In fact you would probably be better to find out all the fields of that form and then just POST to it yourself:

```
var inputs = new NameValueCollection();
inputs.Add("field1", "value1");
inputs.Add("field2", "value2");
inputs.Add("field3", "value3");

System.Net.WebClient Client = new WebClient();
Client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
byte[] POSTResultData = Client.UploadValues(postUrl, inputs);
```