# C# reach click button in webbrowser?

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, click, browser

I want to click event button in webbrowser object.

Button is clicked I want to reach out and write the code? For example, the login button is clicked on the webbrowser object in the pop-up on the site to capture the event and would like to write the code?

Comment: Do you want to get event of clicked button on html page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I write an example for you(how get event clicked button):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Or navigate to your url                
webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<html><body><button id=\"btn1\" type=\"button\">Click Me!</button><button id=\"btn2\" type=\"button\">Click Me!</button></body></html>";
}
```

**Call Click event:**(when page loaded)

```
 private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

     webBrowser1.Document.Click += new HtmlElementEventHandler(Document_Click);
    }
```

**Get Active Element When User click on document**

```
 void Document_Click(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
        {
           //Check Element is Button 
           if (webBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement.TagName == "BUTTON")
           {
             if (webBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement.Id== "your button id")
             {
               //Do someting
             }
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're using the WebBrowser control in C# WinForms and you would like to fire an event when a button is clicked.

The control doesn't have a click event, but the Document does. To do this you can use WebBrowser.Document.Click event and then loop through the HTML elements to find the one that was clicked.

`web.Document.Click += new HtmlElementEventHandler(Document_Click);`

This link will help also: [webbrowser-control-get-element-by-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603164/webbrowser-control-get-element-by-type)