# capture button click event of webpage (opened inside WebBrowser Control) in WinForm?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a WebBrowser Control in WinForm application. A web page (i.e. Yahoo registration) is loaded inside WebBrowser Control.

I want to capture the submit button click event of the webpage into WinForm (which hosts WebBrowser Control). Is there any way to achieve this functionality ?

Thanks,

Comment: Please use this link:-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901997/c-sharp-reach-click-button-in-webbrowser