# Cannot press button programmatically

Tags: html, vb.net

There is a button on a website that looks like this:

```
<input class="submit button signup" type="submit" id="submit_button" value="Sign up">
```

I've been trying to press it programmatically in .net using:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("submit_button").InvokeMember("submit")
```

But it does not work, it stays on the same page always. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click a button or something similar you must invoke the [**`click`**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp) method. [**`submit`**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp) only works for `<form>` tags.

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("submit_button").InvokeMember("click")
```

Here's a list of properties and methods that ***all*** HTML elements inherit: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp

Answer (score -1):

simply input a asp button and it can directly accessible in backend with onclick event. add this in your form.aspx "".
And this way you can access it the click event in backend. 
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{//code here }

Comment: OP is trying to click a button in an embedded browser control; they do not have control of the page markup.

Comment: @AndrewMorton You are right, sorry if I didn't ask properly. Do you think you can help though?

Comment: He hasn't even tagged the question with ASP.NET... Based on the `WebBrowser` he's using WinForms.

Comment: Check this solved question. You can get idea as I guess. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901997/c-sharp-reach-click-button-in-webbrowser

Comment: Just to clarify: He wanted to _click_ the button, _**not**_ respond to it _being clicked_.