# Invoking an href click event JavaScript in winforms webbrowser control

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I`m trying to automatically login into one of the online browser games from my application. However when I inspect the login button, I see this html code.

```
<div id="js_login_button">
                <a href="#" onclick="$('#login_submit_button').click()" class="login_button">
                    <span class="button_left"></span>
                    <span class="button_middle">Login</span>
                    <span class="button_right"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
```

Since I can`t reach the button's id, I wasn't able to use

```
webbrowser.Document.GetElementById("button_id").InvokeMember("click");
```

How can I invoke these kind of buttons ?

**Edit:** For whom wondering which game is it:
https://www.tribalwars.net/

```
<form action="index.php?action=login&amp;show_server_selection=1" method="post" id="login_form" onsubmit="return Index.login_submit();" data-tracked="true">
    <div>
        <label for="user">
            <strong>User name:</strong>
            <span>
                <input id="user" name="user" class="text" type="text" value="" onkeydown="if((e=window.event||event) &amp;&amp; e.keyCode == 13 &amp;&amp; $('#user').val() &amp;&amp; $('#password').val()) $('#login_form').submit()" data-tracked="true">
            </span>
        </label>
        <label for="password">
            <strong>Password:</strong>
            <span>
                <input name="clear" type="hidden" value="true" data-tracked="true">
                <input id="password" name="password" class="text" type="password" onkeydown="if((e=window.event||event) &amp;&amp; e.keyCode == 13 &amp;&amp; $('#user').val() &amp;&amp; $('#password').val()) $('#login_form').submit()" data-tracked="true">
            </span>
        </label>

        <input type="submit" id="login_submit_button" style="display: none" data-tracked="true">

        <label for="cookie" class="remember_me">
            <input id="cookie" type="checkbox" name="cookie" value="true" checked="checked" data-tracked="true">
                Remember me
        </label>

        <div id="login-buttons">
                            <a id="fb-login-button" class="social-login-button" href="https://ipp-facebook.innogames.de/?game=staemme&amp;market=en&amp;" title="Play with Facebook"></a>

            <div id="js_login_button">
                <a href="#" onclick="$('#login_submit_button').click()" class="login_button">
                    <span class="button_left"></span>
                    <span class="button_middle">Login</span>
                    <span class="button_right"></span>
                </a>
            </div>          
        </div>

        <br style="clear:both;">
    </div>
</form>
```

On this page, the button named **Login** has the same property.

Edit 2: Here is the source code that shows what I tried (and failed):

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    browser.Navigate("https://www.tribalwars.net/"); // browser is defined in the form as a WebBrowser element
}

private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //var debug = browser.Document.GetElementById("login_submit_button").InvokeMember("click"); // there is a runtime null referance error here

    var elements = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("Login");

    foreach (HtmlElement element in elements)
    {
        // The program does not enter here, there is no element !
        //element.InnerHTML to see if it's the one you want
        element.InvokeMember("click");

    }
}
```

Comment: @EdPlunkett its windows forms.

Comment: Well, it's not a button. It's an anchor tag. You want to execute its onclick event. But you need to get the element first. Does the winforms webbrowser control have any other ways to enumerate or access elements in the page? Any way to enumerate all of a particular type of tag? How many other a tags in the page do you potentially need to wade through to find this one?

Comment: @EdPlunkett No I think it doesn't. But from the line I provided, I am able to see how the event is executed right ? Isn`t there a way to make a call ?

Comment: Cant use GetElementsByTagName? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603164/webbrowser-control-get-element-by-type once you have the element object, you can probably find a way to invoke it's onclick event.

Comment: @EdPlunkett What is the tag here ?

Comment: Aren't you trying to simulate a click on the a tag? The span is inert.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I dont know why, but I cant reach the element by tag. GetElementsByTagName returns null when I use the span tag. The element I`m looking for is buried in a deep location, maybe I have to do some kind of iteration to reach to it ?

Comment: A) Why do you care about the span? What does it have to do with anything? B) exactly what are you passing to GetElementsByTagName()?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I changed my question little bit, so that an unregistered user can understand what Im talking about. In this version Im passing `Login` as a tag. However the function returns null.

Comment: Can you show me the code where you are "passing Login as a tag"? I'm curious about what that means. But now that you've changed your story about what HTML is in the webbrowser control, try this and see what you get: `webbrowser.Document.GetElementById("login_submit_button").InvokeMember("click");`

Comment: @EdPlunkett Sorry, it took a while for me to post the source code. You can find it in my post.

Comment: HTML tag names are the tags: "a", "div", "span", etc. There is nothing in the HTML there named "Login". Not a tag, not an id, not a name. Nothing. Why, of all imaginable sequences of characters, did you put "Login" between those quotation marks? What made you think it identified anything in that HTML? Especially after I told you that you were simulating a click on the a tag? Doesn't matter; you're giving me totally different HTML now.

Comment: What happened when you tried my last suggestion, 9 hours ago, with `getElementById("login_submit_button")`?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Okay, I'm sorry i promise i won't do it again relax and drink your coffee :)) Yeah I misunderstood the example in the link you provided me. The get element by id is giving me a run-time null reference error as you can see it on the source code.

Comment: Huh. What happens with `var debug = browser.Document.GetElementById("login_submit_button")`; is it GetElementById that's returning null? Guessing it is (though I'm not sure why), but I'd like to be sure. Try getting "login_form" by id too; all the button is, is a submit button, so submitting the form programmatically should have the same effect as faking a click on that button. Also try getting "input" and "form" elements by tag name and looking at the results in the debugger.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Man you were right, I was able to reach the button by the span tag. I dont know how the member click works with span but it did ! Please provide a solution that I will accept. Just write down the same example in the link I`ll edit it in the form that worked for me. Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Delighted to help! So did you do `GetElementById("button_middle")`? What was it exactly that worked? Or did you do `GetElementsByTagName("span")` and click on all of them?

Comment: I see now where you were getting "Login" from. That's just some text displayed inside something, not a name or identifier you can use to look anything up by. In desperation you could have enumerated all the span tags and looked for the one with that as its `innerText` property, if all else failed. That's ugly though.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I got the element by `GetElementsByTagName("span")` then I clicked on `element.InnerHtml.Contains("Login")` I tried `browser.Document.GetElementById("login_submit_button")` and `browser.Document.GetElementById("button_middle")` but both of them gave the same null reference error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A faked click on that `"button_middle"` span tag should work; I expect the click event will bubble up to its parent, the `a` tag, which has an onclick event that submits the form.

```
var elements = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span");

foreach (HtmlElement element in elements)
{
    // If there's more than one button, you can check the
    //element.InnerHTML to see if it's the one you want
    if (element.InnerHtml != null && element.InnerHtml.Contains("Login"))
    {
        element.InvokeMember("click");
    }
}
```